# Firebase emulator not authenticating suddenly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I opened our firebase functions code today, typed `firebase serve` as I usually do, but when I called an http function that touches our real-time database, I was greeted with this message:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: invalid_grant (Bad Request)\". There are two likely causes: (1) your server time is not properly synced or (2) your certificate key file has been revoked. To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project. If not, generate a new key file at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk."}

Nothing changed from when I was able to run this last (a couple weeks ago?) and my system time is set to automatic for time and timezone.  I ran `firebase logout` and `firebase login` and I'm using the parameterless `admin.initializeApp();`.  Has something changed I need to take into account?

Comment: I've since updated the firebase-cli, removed node_modules and `npm-install`ed, tried `firebase emulators:start --only functions,database`, but it all results in the same error message when trying to call a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the information found @ https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator to generate and set up a key file @ https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/details/##################?authuser=0&project=my-project-name by clicking 'create key' at the bottom.

[image]

Once the key file was downloaded, I set it with this command line in my projects directory

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path\to\key.json`

With that done, I was able to run my functions as I expected locally.

I love you all.